# 22.04LTS ‎DS-SC4B Crashing USB Controller

Tags: usb, 22.04, crash, usb-drive, xhci-hcd

I got an issue with an external USB enclosure (4 ports) ‎DS-SC4B based on the

> ASMedia Technology ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s
> bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge, ASM1153E SATA 6Gb/s bridge

The enclosure works fine on MacOs and Windows. On Ubuntu it is crashing (especially while write operations).

The drive is crashing with:

```
    [ 9387.214796] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: ERROR unknown event type 15
    [ 9392.217460] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command.
    [ 9392.217476] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: USBSTS: 0x00000000
    [ 9392.217512] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
    [ 9392.217550] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
    [ 9392.217628] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
    [ 9392.217949] usb 4-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
    [ 9392.217962] usb 4-2.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
    [ 9392.261606] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
    [ 9392.261689] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
    [ 9392.263688] usb 4-2.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 9392.273367] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 30546784960 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x104000 phys_seg 64 prio class 0
[ 9392.273383] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc2, logical block 3818296664, lost async page write
[ 9392.273395] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc2, logical block 3818296665, lost async page write
[ 9392.273401] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc2, logical block 3818296666, lost async page write
[ 9392.273406] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc2, logical block 3818296667, lost async page write
[ 9392.273412] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc2, logical block 3818296668, lost async page write
```

I tried to disable UAS, which is recommended by some users, but it doesnt help anything,
i also tried to disable writecache since I thought it might be the root of my issue:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/64C6-CBEF       /mnt/hd99_00_20 exfat-fuse   auto,uid=1001,gid=1002,umask=077,exec,rw,noatime,flush,nofail     0 0
```

The syslog only shows:

```
Oct 28 19:43:05 lukasserver kernel: [ 9392.217628] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
Oct 28 19:43:05 lukasserver kernel: [ 9392.217949] usb 4-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
Oct 28 19:43:05 lukasserver kernel: [ 9392.217962] usb 4-2.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
Oct 28 19:43:05 lukasserver kernel: [ 9392.263688] usb 4-2.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
```

I dont know how to do anything further. Has anyone a tip for me?

The usb output looks like this:

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 10000M
        ID 2109:0822 VIA Labs, Inc. 
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 10000M
            ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge, ASM1153E SATA 6Gb/s bridge
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 10000M
            ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge, ASM1153E SATA 6Gb/s bridge
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        ID 2109:2822 VIA Labs, Inc. 
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
    ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    |__ Port 7: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        ID 8087:0aa7 Intel Corp. Wireless-AC 3168 Bluetooth
    |__ Port 7: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        ID 8087:0aa7 Intel Corp. Wireless-AC 3168 Bluetooth
```

The system is a GB-BRi5(H)-8250 from Gigabyte.

This is the relevant dmesg output after boot:

```
  1.588609] usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.631391] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] failed to retrieve link info, disabling eDP
[    1.639213] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20201103 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    1.641267] ACPI: video: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    1.641512] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input3
[    1.651354] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
[    1.656208] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed Plus Gen 2x1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.661163] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
[    1.670821] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
[    1.706471] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0822, bcdDevice=90.13
[    1.706481] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    1.706485] usb 4-2: Product: USB3.1 Hub             
[    1.706488] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.         
[    1.706491] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: 000000001
[    1.711518] hub 4-2:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.712224] hub 4-2:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    1.742345] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0aa7, bcdDevice= 0.01
[    1.742357] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.828649] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    2.008264] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=2822, bcdDevice=90.13
[    2.008289] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.008302] usb 3-2: Product: USB2.0 Hub             
[    2.008311] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.         
[    2.008320] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 000000001
[    2.015373] hub 3-2:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.018254] hub 3-2:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    2.365536] usb 4-2.1: new SuperSpeed Plus Gen 2x1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.395573] usb 4-2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=55aa, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    2.395598] usb 4-2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[    2.395612] usb 4-2.1: Product: ASM235CM
[    2.395620] usb 4-2.1: Manufacturer: ASMT
[    2.395628] usb 4-2.1: SerialNumber: 914000000E84
[    2.485546] usb 4-2.2: new SuperSpeed Plus Gen 2x1 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    2.515567] usb 4-2.2: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=55aa, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    2.515592] usb 4-2.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[    2.515606] usb 4-2.2: Product: ASM235CM
[    2.515614] usb 4-2.2: Manufacturer: ASMT
[    2.515622] usb 4-2.2: SerialNumber: 914000000E83
[    2.533485] usb 4-2.1: UAS is ignored for this device, using usb-storage instead
[    2.533494] usb-storage 4-2.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    2.533815] usb-storage 4-2.1:1.0: Quirks match for vid 174c pid 55aa: c00000
[    2.533892] scsi host1: usb-storage 4-2.1:1.0
[    2.534013] usb 4-2.2: UAS is ignored for this device, using usb-storage instead
[    2.534020] usb-storage 4-2.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    2.534193] usb-storage 4-2.2:1.0: Quirks match for vid 174c pid 55aa: c00000
[    2.534317] scsi host2: usb-storage 4-2.2:1.0
[    2.534402] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    2.535962] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[    3.368631] raid6: avx2x4   gen() 37790 MB/s
[    3.436630] raid6: avx2x4   xor() 12482 MB/s
[    3.504636] raid6: avx2x2   gen() 35389 MB/s
[    3.553655] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ASMT     ASM235CM         0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[    3.553705] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ASMT     ASM235CM         0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[    3.553875] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[    3.553956] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 39063650304 512-byte logical blocks: (20.0 TB/18.2 TiB)
[    3.553960] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    3.554004] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[    3.554139] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdc] 39063650304 512-byte logical blocks: (20.0 TB/18.2 TiB)
[    3.554146] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdc] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    3.555048] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    3.555051] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[    3.555348] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[    3.555355] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[    3.556549] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    3.556618] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    3.561475]  sdc: sdc1 sdc2
[    3.563814] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[    3.572635] raid6: avx2x2   xor() 21308 MB/s
[    3.588604]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
[    3.590793] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[    3.640600] raid6: avx2x1   gen() 20816 MB/s
[    3.708637] raid6: avx2x1   xor() 14601 MB/s
[    3.776635] raid6: sse2x4   gen() 15365 MB/s
[    3.844636] raid6: sse2x4   xor()  9139 MB/s
[    3.912631] raid6: sse2x2   gen() 15776 MB/s
[    3.980637] raid6: sse2x2   xor()  9669 MB/s
[    4.048636] raid6: sse2x1   gen() 13342 MB/s
[    4.116636] raid6: sse2x1   xor()  6636 MB/s
[    4.116639] raid6: using algorithm avx2x4 gen() 37790 MB/s
[    4.116641] raid6: .... xor() 12482 MB/s, rmw enabled
[    4.116643] raid6: using avx2x2 recovery algorithm
[    4.117473] xor: measuring software checksum speed
[    4.117853]    prefetch64-sse  : 26060 MB/sec
[    4.118280]    generic_sse     : 23171 MB/sec
[    4.118282] xor: using function: prefetch64-sse (26060 MB/sec)
[    4.118925] async_tx: api initialized (async)
[    4.292830] Btrfs loaded, crc32c=crc32c-intel, zoned=yes, fsverity=yes
[    4.363297] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[    4.586411] systemd[1]: Inserted module 'autofs4'
[    4.646989] systemd[1]: systemd 249.11-0ubuntu3.11 running in system mode (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +APPARMOR +IMA +SMACK +SECCOMP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +OPENSSL +ACL +BLKID +CURL +ELFUTILS +FIDO2 +IDN2 -IDN +IPTC +KMOD +LIBCRYPTSETUP +LIBFDISK +PCRE2 -PWQUALITY -P11KIT -QRENCODE +BZIP2 +LZ4 +XZ +ZLIB +ZSTD -XKBCOMMON +UTMP +SYSVINIT default-hierarchy=unified)
```

How can I debug this any further, what should I try?

Thanks